# .Net Maui Picker.ItemsSource does not update the picker after being manually set (Windows)

Tags: c#, maui

I have a code that works fine on Maui with Android, but it's not working well on Windows. He does not initialize on first click.

```
            <Picker x:Name="pickerMarca"
                Title="Selecione a marca"
                HorizontalOptions="Center"
                FontSize="20"
                BackgroundColor="Red"                  
                SelectedIndexChanged="SelecionarMarca">
            </Picker>
```

```
    private void CarregarMarca(string veiculo)
    {
        pickerMarca.ItemsSource = MarcaRepositorio.ListarMarcas(veiculo);
        pickerMarca.ItemDisplayBinding = new Binding("nome");
    }

    public void SelecionarMarca(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var pickerMarca = (Picker)sender;
        int selectedIndex = pickerMarca.SelectedIndex;

        if (selectedIndex != -1)
        {
            Marca marca = (Marca)pickerMarca.ItemsSource[selectedIndex];
            selCodigoMarca = marca.codigo;

            CarregarModelo(selCodigoMarca);
        }
    }
```

I did found a workaround but as a array I have the problem to show the binding "name" because my model has two attributes.

https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/9739

So my doubt is. Is there a way to use the workaround but show the "nome" property of my model?

Or even better. Is there a way to maintain my code but somehow make work on Windows?

Thanks.

Comment: Maybe you are looking for `ItemDisplayBinding`? Something like `ItemDisplayBinding="{Binding Name}"`?

Comment: I'm already using it. The problem happens only on Windows and only if a need to use the workaround listed here:

https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/9739

Comment: Have you set `picker.ItemsSource = picker.GetItemsAsArray();` that the [link](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/9739) recommended ?